# JQXGrid filter not working with Dynamic data

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqxgrid, jqxwidgets, jqwidget

I recently started using JQXGrid, I used its filter in an example it was working fine then I included it into my app where JQXGrid takes dynamic data so when I click on the filter options it goes down nothing works after. The text box for putting value just disappears and when you click outside you can not open the filter drop down again.

So I figured out it was my mistake I did not considered its CSS file which was causing this trouble.

But I am still facing some issue I am using 3-4 Grids inside the page and all of them are getting lot of data due to which it becomes it starts to lag.... the filters and scrolling become very slow.
Is there anything I am doing wrong or is there any work around.

Answer (score 0):

Do you update the data by setting the jqxGrid "source" property to new dataAdapter? If not, may be you should try.